# Toggle arrow only for currently selected table header

Tags: jquery

How can I target only the currently selected table header (just as the color changes only for the selected header), so that the arrow next to it is the only one that is toggled to rotate on click?

```
<table class="container cf">
  <thead class="cf">
    <tr>
      <th class="numeric">amount <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">case <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">field 3 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">field 4 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">location <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">date <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="verdicts">
    <tr>
      <td data-title="amount" class="amount">8,570,000.00<span class="result"></span></td>
      <td data-title="case">title</td>
      <td data-title="practice area">area</td>
      <td data-title="user">Bob jones</td>
      <td data-title="location">Orlando, FL</td>
      <td data-title="date">Mar 6, 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="amount" class="amount">$447,115<span class="result"></span></td>
      <td data-title="case">Another title</td>
      <td data-title="practice area">area</td>
      <td data-title="user">Joe Smith</td>
      <td data-title="location">Orlando, FL</td>
      <td data-title="date">Mar 6, 2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(".numeric").click(function() {
  $(".numeric").removeClass('numeric-active');
  $(this).toggleClass("numeric-active");
  $(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom").toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mrdag8bk/4/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
$(".numeric").click(function() {
  $(".numeric").removeClass('numeric-active');
  $(this).toggleClass("numeric-active");
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/mrdag8bk/8/

Answer (score 0):

Find your element within the context of the element that the event was triggered on:

```
$(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom", this).toggleClass("rotate");
```

Or

```
$(this).find(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom").toggleClass("rotate");
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrdag8bk/6/)

Comment: The problem is that the red color should be removed from the previously clicked header when another header is clicked.

Comment: @Matt That is the behaviour I can see.

Comment: I see it doing the correct thing now, but its doing the same thing as the other solution: applying a ::before pseudo class to the word, so there's a box showing up to the left of the word on toggle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".numeric").click(function() {
    $(".numeric").removeClass('numeric-active');
    $(this).toggleClass("numeric-active");
    $(this).children("i").toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrdag8bk/7/

Comment: This is just about what I was looking for, except I'm seeing a small box to the left of the header when toggled, that appears to be a missing glyphicon. All it should do is rotate the arrow on click, not apply any ::before pseudo class.